# JAXB - Move dynamically generated namespaces to document root

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I've got this POJO, encapsulating a dynamic, non-nested element of an Atom entry:

```
public class SimpleElement {

    private Namespace namespace;
    private String tagName;
    private String value;
    private Collection<Attribute> attributes;

    /* getters/setters/... */
```

And for completeness, `Attribute`

```
public class Attribute {

    private String name;
    private String value;
    private Namespace namespace;  

    /* getters/setters/... */
```

And `Namespace`:

```
public class Namespace {

    private final String uri;
    private final String prefix;

    /* getters/setters/... */
```

`SimpleElementAdapter` serializes a `SimpleElement` into its `org.w3c.dom.Element` counterpart.

The only problem with this approach is that namespaces always end up at element level, never at document root.

Is there a way to dynamically declare namespaces at document root?

Comment: Possible dupe, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996135/how-to-marshal-multiple-namespaces-to-xml-root-element-with-jaxb

Comment: Not a dupe, the namespaces in my case are not known in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## MY RECOMMENDATION

My recommendation is to let the JAXB implementation write the namespace declarations as it sees fit.  As long as the elements are properly namespace qualified it does not really matter where the namespace declarations occur.

If you ignore my recommendation, below is an approach you can use.

---

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

### Specify the Namespaces to Include on Root Element

You can use the `NamespacePrefixMapper` extension to add extra namespace declarations to the root element (see:  https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.11/docs/ch05.html#prefixmapper).  You will need to derive from your own object model what namespaces should be declared at the root.

**Note:** `NamespacePrefixMapper` is in the `com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller` package.  This means you will need the JAXB refereince implementation jar on your classpath (see: https://jaxb.java.net/).

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.*;

public class MyNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris2() {
        return new String[] {"ns1", "http://www.example.com/FOO", "ns2", "http://www.example.com/BAR"};
    }


}
```

### Specify the `NamespacePrefixMapper` on the `Marshaller`

The `com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper` property is used to specify the `NamespacePrefixMapper` on the `Marshaller`.

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper());
```

### Demo Code

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private Object object;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElementNS("http://www.example.com/FOO", "ns1:foo");
        foo.setObject(element);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper());
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is sample output that will be produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/FOO" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/BAR">
    <ns1:foo/>
</foo>
```

---

## UPDATE

> Clear answer, thanks. However, I need access to the NSMapper from
>   SimpleElementAdapter. What do you suggest? The only way I see right
>   now is making the NSMapper a mutable singleton so that
>   SimpleElementAdapter can add namespaces if needed.

I forgot about your `XmlAdapter`.

### Java Model

Below is a more complicated iteration of the model, where instead of `Foo` holding an instance of a DOM element, it holds and instance of `Bar` that gets adapted into an instance of a DOM element.

**Foo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BarAdapter.class)
    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Bar**

```
public class Bar {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**BarAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class BarAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Bar>{

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Bar bar) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElementNS("http://www.example.com/BAR", "ns:bar");
        element.setTextContent(bar.getValue());
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public Bar unmarshal(Object arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

### Grab Namespace Declarations

Since your object model does not hold the DOM elements directly you can't traverse it to get the namespace declarations.  Instead we could do a marshal to a `ContentHandler` to collect them. Below are the reasons for marshalling to a `ContentHandler`:

1. It gives us an easy event which we can use to collection the namespace declarations.
2. It doesn't actually produce anything so it is the lightest marshal target we can use.

```java
NsContentHandler contentHandler = new NsContentHandler();
marshaller.marshal(foo, contentHandler);
```

**NsContentHandler**

The implementation of `ContentHandler` will look something like:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class NsContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Map<String, String> namespaces = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri) throws SAXException {
        if(!namespaces.containsKey(prefix)) {
            namespaces.put(prefix, uri);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getNamespaces() {
        return namespaces;
    }

}
```

### Specify the Namespaces to Include on Root Element

The implementation of `MyNamespacePrefixMapper` changes a little to use the namrespaces captured from our `ContentHandler`.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.*;

public class MyNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {

    private String[] namespaces;

    public MyNamespacePrefixMapper(Map<String, String> namespaces) {
        this.namespaces = new String[namespaces.size() * 2];
        int index = 0;
        for(Entry<String, String> entry : namespaces.entrySet()) {
            this.namespaces[index++] = entry.getKey();
            this.namespaces[index++] = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris2() {
        return namespaces;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setValue("Hello World");
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar(bar);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

        // Marshal First Time to Get Namespace Declarations
        NsContentHandler contentHandler = new NsContentHandler();
        marshaller.marshal(foo, contentHandler);

        // Marshal Second Time for Real
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper(contentHandler.getNamespaces()));
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/BAR">
    <ns:bar>Hello World</ns:bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: Clear answer, thanks.
However, I need access to the NSMapper from `SimpleElementAdapter`. What do you suggest? The only way I see right now is making the NSMapper a mutable singleton so that `SimpleElementAdapter` can add namespaces if needed.

Comment: @Rolf - I have updated my answer to factor in the `XmlAdapter`.